# Setting a Button in a sub?

Tags: vb.net

So, I have a little problem. Im making a application (in visual basic), and I have a way so that I can set a color when you hover over it. Now, I want to do this for all buttons, but make it a little easier by making a sub that can do this for me. The problem is, how can my sub tell which button to initialize the custom hover color? Here is my code.

```
 Private Sub initButton(ByVal color As Color)
    Button1.TabStop = False
    Button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
    Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = color
    Button1.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = color
    Button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = color
    Button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = color
 End Sub
```

Now, how can I set Button1 to the button I want to initialize? Is there anyway to put that as an argument? If you find a answer, please reply.

Comment: put  your code in the Hover event and hook all the buttons to the same event handler; the *sender* param will be the current control being hovered over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Plutonix suggested, using the Hover Event of the buttons would be the first logical choice.  You will need to add a Parameter to your your Sub to pass in the button being hovered over.

```
 Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
   Handles Button1.MouseHover,Button2.MouseHover 'add more buttons....
    initButton(CType(sender, Button),Color.Blue)
 End Sub

 Private Sub initButton(hoverButton As Button, ByVal color As Color)
     hoverButton.TabStop = False
     hoverButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
     hoverButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
     hoverButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = color
     hoverButton.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = color
     hoverButton.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = color
     hoverButton.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = color
 End Sub
```

Comment: This will fail with Option Strict On (and I recommend always having Option Strict On) as sender is an Object instead of a Button. I suggest changing the initButton call to `initButton(CType(sender, Button), Color.Blue)`

Comment: @Blackwood you are correct.  I was toying with hoverButton as Object and lost track of my changes.  I should have proof read better... Thank you.